# Avro tool fails to convert from json due to IPv6

Tags: json, dns, ipv6, avro

I am trying to convert a simple json file to avro using avro tools (1.7.7).

The command I've been running

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fromjson 
--schema-file src/main/avro/twitter.avsc tweet.json > tweet.avro
```

on this schema

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "tweet",
"namespace": "co.feeb.avro",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "username",
        "type": "string",
        "doc": "screen name of the user on twitter.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "text",
        "type": "string",
        "doc": "the content of the user's message"
    },
    {
        "name": "timestamp",
        "type": "long",
        "doc": "unix epoch time in seconds"
    }
],
"doc": "Schema for twitter messages"
}
```

I see this exception after running this command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:409)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:395)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1436)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1337)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:244)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:122)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
at org.apache.avro.tool.Util.openFromFS(Util.java:88)
at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileWriteTool.run(DataFileWriteTool.java:82)
at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:84)
at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:73)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "810d:340:1770::1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<init>(DnsClient.java:127)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.<init>(Resolver.java:61)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.getResolver(DnsContext.java:573)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:103)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbServiceLocator.getKerberosService(KrbServiceLocator.java:85)
at sun.security.krb5.Config.checkRealm(Config.java:1120)
at sun.security.krb5.Config.getRealmFromDNS(Config.java:1093)
at sun.security.krb5.Config.getDefaultRealm(Config.java:987)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:81)
```

Trying to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 using -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true didn't help. (I am running Mac OSX 10.10.3 and Java 1.8.0_25-b17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh snap ... I've solved it myself right after posting this. My local router added an IPv6 nameserver to my local machine.

Changing the assigned nameserver manually to Google's 8.8.8.8 fixed the issue.

Comment: Besides the "normal" Google 8.8.8.8  and 8.8.4.4, Google has IPv6 name servers: 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844. A modern OS will prefer IPv6 over IPv4 if both network stacks are configured.

Comment: yepp, but the issue is that the Java libraries used seem to not support IPv6